# How to call an ASPX/ASCX method from ASP.NET MVC button_click

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

Not sure if my requirement is bit weird... However, i need to call a method which is resided in .ascx.cs page from mvc on button click

in MVC

i have button in layout page

```
<input type="button" id="btnHomeSearch" value="Search Page" />
```

on click of this button i have a jquery POST method which is intended to call the .ascx (ASP.NET usercontrol method) method.

```
$('#btnHomeSearch').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'SDLCSearch.ascx.cs/HomePageSearch',
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
        }
    });
});
```

which is not working... Can anyone please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up client and server code.  You're also mixing up MVC and web forms, but guess you know that, and have them in separate projects etc.

If you want to post data to a UserControl (.ascx), you'll need to place the UserControl on a normal page (.aspx), and pass the method call through from the .aspx.cs to the .ascx.cs file appropriately.

The post method you have should be posting to the URL of the .aspx page, e.g. '/SDLCSearch.aspx'

Comment: Thanks for your reply Paul. I have tried posting to aspx page but it is not posting to tat method.

Comment: You have to either put the code in Page_Load, and retrieve the data using Request.Form["DataKey"], or otherwise use a Public Page Method:  http://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/archive/2011/12/24/page-methods-in-asp-net.aspx